# Count the elements of $M_n \setminus M_{n+1}$, where $M_n$ is a downward filtered sequence of semigroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb N$ be the additive monoid of natural numbers, and let $k$ be a positive integer. I am working with the quotient monoid $M = \mathbb N^3 / \sim$, where two triplets are equivalent if they differ by an integer multiple of $(1,1,-k)$. Denote by $[x,y,z]$ the equivalence class of $(x,y,z)$.

Now consider the downward filtered sequence of subsemigroups

$$M_n = \{ [x,y,z] \in M : x + y + z \ge n \}$$

How can I compute the cardinality of each of the sets $M_n \setminus M_{n+1}$?

**NOTE:** An element of $M$ is in $M_n$ if it has at least one representative $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $x + y + z \ge n$. It is not necessary that all representatives satisfy this condition.

Comment: Where did this problem come from? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Do your natural numbers include $0,$ or are they the positive integers? Different sources use the name differently.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: My natural numbers include $0$, for otherwise $\mathbb N$ would not be a monoid.

Comment: Ah, of course. I often get semigroup and monoid mixed up.

Comment: I correct my previous inaccuracy. Consider $\mathbb C[x^k, y^k, xy]$ as a graded subring of $\mathbb C[x,y]$, and let $\mathfrak m$ be its irrelevant ideal. I want to compute the dimensions of the $\mathbb C$-vector spaces $\mathfrak m^n / \mathfrak m^{n+1}$. Note that each $M_n$ is in $1-1$ correspondence with the $\mathbb C$-basis of monomials in $\mathfrak m^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the elements of $M$ which have a representative with $x+y+z=n,$ and no higher.

**Show:** Every element $u\in M$ has a unique representative $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in u$ with $x_0y_0=0.$ If $k\geq 2,$ this is also a representative of $u$ with maximal sum $x+y+z.$

So, given $n,$ there is one $(0,0,n)$ and $n$ each of $(0,i,n-i)$ and $(i,0,n-i),$ for $i=1,\dots,n.$

That is a total of $2n+1.$

---

The case $k=1$ is separate.

When $k=1,$ the maximal sum $x+y+z$ is gotten with $z=0.$ So you need to count pairs $(x,y)$ with $x+y= n.$ That is $n+1.$

Comment: Wow, thanks! I had already noticed that each monomial in the ring has a unique representative of the form $(x^k)^a (y^k)^b (xy)^c$, where either $a$ or $b$ is zero. But I missed the fact that this representative maximizes the sum $a + b + c$.