# Compute the dimensions of the vector spaces $\mathfrak m^n / \mathfrak m^{n+1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Let $R = \mathbb C[u, v^2, vw, w^2]$, and let $\mathfrak p$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $u^2 + v^2 + (w^2)^{k+1}$, for some $k \ge 0$. I want to compute the dimensions of the $\mathbb C$-vector spaces $\mathfrak m^n / \mathfrak m^{n+1}$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of $R / \mathfrak p$ at the origin.

Based on [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4270740/4675), I tried to solve the problem as follows. Notice that $\mathfrak m^n$ is generated as a $\mathbb C$-vector space by the monomials $u^a v^b w^{b + 2c}$ where $a + b + c \ge n$. However, the generators with $b \ge 2$ are redundant, because

$$\left( u^{a+2} v^b w^{b+2c} \right) \cdot w^2 + \left( u^a v^{b+2} w^{(b+2)+2c} \right) + \left( u^a v^b w^{b+2(c+2)} \right) \cdot w^{2k} = 0$$

Since there are no other algebraic relations between $u,v,w$, we conclude that,

- The monomials $u^a v^b w^{b+2c}$ with $a + b + c \ge n$ and $b = 0, 1$ form a basis of $\mathfrak m^n$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space.
- The monomials $u^a v^b w^{b+2c}$ with $a + b + c = n$ and $b = 0, 1$ form a basis of $\mathfrak m^n / \mathfrak m^{n+1}$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space.
- For $b = 0$, the equation $a + c = n$ has $n + 1$ solutions.
- For $b = 1$, the equation $a + c = n - 1$ has $n$ solutions.
- $\mathfrak m^n / \mathfrak m^{n+1}$ is a $(2n+1)$-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: It seems your ring is isomorphic to $R/\mathfrak{p} \cong \mathbb{C}[u,v,w]/(v^2+(u^2+w^{k+1})w^2)$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}:=(u,v,w)$ - maybe this simplifies your calculations. Note that $\mathbb{C}[v^2,vw,w^2] \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2)$.

Comment: - If the sequence $u,v,w$ was a regular sequence, you would have the formula $Sym^n(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2) \cong \mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$, but the ring is singular at this point. What you have is a surjection $\phi:Sym^n(\mathfrak{m}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}^n \rightarrow 0$, and you must estimate the kernel.